# Most productive workflow to create animated display ads

Tags: svg, animation

I am currently working on over a dozen display ads using Google Web Designer.
I use the Static template and animate within GWD to export as a mix of SVG and HTML files that comply with Google's Display ads policies.

At the moment my creative workflow is pretty convoluted.
We create usually 4 sizes of an ad with 4 different texts for each size.
I create Illustrator templates.  Each vector image I import into GWD has to be converted to SVG to retain Brand fonts, so I end up creating 32 vector assets for 4 ads, for example.

If there is a last minute change, I have to go back and change it in Illustrator to export to SVG and then re-import the edited file into GWD. Outlining text on export in AI doesn't always work, so I end up having to redo a lot of things when a font reverts to the default one.

I feel like since I'm working with AI, After Effects would be a better tool to handle my animated files (to skip having to export as SVG), but AE doesn't export vector animations, so I could only create GIFs which might be too heavy for Google.

**Is there a simpler workflow to produce vector-based animations for display ads featuring custom fonts than my current workflow?**

Comment: AE +bodymoving can export vectors

Comment: Can you show me where it says that on their website? Can you share an example of files exported that way? I’m dubious and I’ve looked at their website a few times but they are very vague

Comment: Thats what it does, it exports them as json that a javascript player built in or lottie plays as either html, svg or canvas animations. But AE was not really designed for this so it only supports a subset of features . But why dont you just try it  its free you know. Not that it necceserily is useful in your context since it requires lottie as a player.